# How to compute $[GF(128):GF(16)]$ and $[GF(3^6):GF(3^3)]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to compute $[GF(128):GF(16)]$ and $[GF(3^6):GF(3^3)]$, where GF stands for Galois field. I know $128=2^7, 16=2^4,$ but what can I do next? I am really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply: we know finite fields are unique up to isomorphism, and $\mathbf F_{p^r}\subset\mathbf F_{p^s}$ if and only if $r\mid s$.

Thus the first number doesn't exist and $\;[\mathbf F_{3^6}:\mathbf F_{3^3}]=2$.